# Add-type assembly only gets loaded when running script two times

Tags: powershell

Im currently trying to create a script which takes all XML files in a folder which are older than 6 months and create a .zip file with them.
On the first try, when I execute the script, the following errormessage gets thrown:

```
Unable to find type [System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode]. Make sure that the assembly that contains this type is loaded.
At line:14 char:1
+ [System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive] $arch = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

which tells me, that my add-type commandlet didn't work properly, because the assembly didn't get load.
but when I execute the script for the second time in my ISE Session, the script works perfectly. I did some research but couldn't find a answer to this.
My code is below:
Does anybody have any idea on why this doesn't work on the first run?

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

$Date = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-(6))
#path where files should be archived from
$path = "xxxx"
$dateforfile = $Date.ToString("yyyyMM")
$pathforfile = $path  + "XML-$dateforfile.zip"
$items = Get-ChildItem -path $path | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -le $Date) -and ($_.Name -like "*.xml")} | select FullName

# creates empty zip file:
[System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive] $arch = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open("$pathforfile",[System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode]::Update)

# add your files to zip
Get-ChildItem -path $path | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -le $Date) -and ($_.Name -like "*.xml")} | foreach {[System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::CreateEntryFromFile($arch,$_.FullName,$_.Name)}
# zip will be updated with files after you close it. 
$arch.Dispose()

#removes xml files from basefolder
foreach($i in $items){
Remove-Item $i.FullName | Where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } 
}
```

Comment: `ZipArchiveMode` is in the `[System.IO.Compression]` namespace. Add a `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression` line.

Comment: What is the reason for not using `Compress-Archive`? It would remove the need for `Add-Type` and simplify the code that adds files to the ZIP.

Comment: @Hazrelle, thank you this worked! I just don't really understand, why it worked without this additional line on the second try, i mean there weren't any new assemblies added.

Comment: @zett42 this was just the first idea I came up with but you are right, compress-archive would've been the better solution!

Comment: This is because the first time you execute the script `[System.IO.Compression]` is not available but I guess PowerShell add the type for you when it does encounter the error. So on next run this is available.